# Can I test Granger causality in cyclical components?

Tags: finance, applied-econometrics, causality

I want to test Granger causality test in cyclical components of GDP and private credit, obtained with Christiano-Fitzgerald filter in annual growth rates of quarterly data. The main purpose is to find the **relation between business and financial cycle**. The problem is that I don't know if unit root tests are able to identify stationary series when there is a cyclical component. Anyway, for this purpose, I follow one paper that assumes that as they are cyclical components, they ARE stationary and continue with the process of select optimal lags for the VAR model and etc. So I try this, but the optimal lag that I found increases as I increase the maximum lag in the test (I tried this in R and eviews), so I don't know what the problem is.

Also following another paper on financial cycles, I applied the Granger causality test in the log level of the original series (NOT THE CYCLICAL COMPONENT), in this I obtained that **GDP causes credit**. But the problem with this, is that the log level series are not stationary and the VAR model has problems of normality and heteroscedasticity. But in the paper says that as the main purpose is just the Granger causality test, it doesn't matter the rest, just to obtain the number of lags (which I'm not sure).

Another solution was to use the annual growth rate of both variables (that are stationary)
for the VAR and also adding dummy variables for normality problems. So with this, I obtained a model that has not autocorrelation, nor heteroscedasticity and has normal residuals, and when applying the Granger causality test, the result is that **Credit causes GDP**, which is the contrary of above!

So now I am confused, first because if I want to study business and financial cycle I should use the cyclical components, right? and on the other side, if cyclical components should not be used in VAR models, should I use the original series or convert them in stationary? Thank you so much if you read all of this, I will appreciate your help.